# “Dann sprechen von” vs. “dann sprechen über”

Tags: preposition

While conversing with a native German speaker I said,

> Manchmal führt die Lebensführung dazu, dass man krank wird.
> **Dann** sprechen wir **über** Lebensführungs-Krankheiten,

whereupon she corrected me to,

> Manchmal führt die Lebensführung dazu, dass man krank wird.
> **Dann** sprechen wir **von** Lebensführungs-Krankheiten.

She said that, had the sentence been the following instead it would have been correct:

> Manchmal führt die Lebensführung dazu, dass man krank wird.
> Wir sprechen **über** Lebensführungs-Krankheiten.

I would appreciate an explanation.

Comment: My understanding is that with *sprechen, denken, schreiben* etc. you use *über* to say what the topic is; see definition 6 in [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C3%BCber). It looks like you're trying to directly translate an idiomatic sense of "we/one speak(s) of", as in "in this situation the word ___ is used." I'm not sure if your friend picked up on that, but for "speak of" as in "mention" you might use *sprechen von*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While in your first example I would use **von** instead of **über**, especially in written language, this is a subtle difference, and I doubt that in everyday spoken language many people would notice this difference (or correct it). If they did, I would consider it as very picky.

Wittgenstein says

> Wo**von** man nicht sprechen kann, dar**über** muß man schweigen.

**not**

> Wor**über** man nicht sprechen kann, da**von** muss man schweigen.

Although the difference is subtle, and the second sentence sounds fine, too, the wo**von** indicates that he speaks about (roughly) "that which you cannot define".

I think the **von** in the context of your example is mostly used to indicate that you give a definition of something, e.g., in your first example the meaning of Lebensfühungs-Krankheiten is defined in the first sentence.

If you use **über** it's a more general statement that you are talking about something.

> Now, we talk about Lebensführungs-Krankheiten.

Here, you have to use **über** and **von** would be wrong (I don't think that the you third example that the native speaker provided is useful to make the distinction clear).

> Jetzt sprechen wir über ...

Answer (score 2):

Wenn wir **von** Voldemort sprechen, dann beziehen wir uns auf "the dark wizard", **ueber** welchen wir nicht sprechen koennen/duerfen.

EDIT (Aus meinem Kommentar)

Siehe auch die vorherige Antwort von user46310, die es ganz gut erklaert.

Der Unterschied ist subtil und umgangssprachlich sollte **ueber** meistens funktionieren. **Von** wird meistens im Zusammenhang mit einer Art Definition verwendet und oft in einer wenn - dann Konstruktion, z.B.

> Wenn ich **von** Lebensfuehrungs-Krankheit spreche, dann meine ich ...

Fuer mich funktioniert **ueber** hier auch, aber zumindest in einem akademischen Kontext ist **von** wohl gebraeuchlicher.

In einer Aussage wie

> In der naechsten Vorlesung sprechen wir **ueber** Lebensfuehrungs-Krankheit.

waere **von** falsch.

Ich denke **sprechen von** ist auch gebraeuchlicher in poetischer Sprache

> Sie sprach von fernen Laendern, Feen und Drachen ...

Comment: Okay, aber wann ist denn "von" und wann "über"?

Comment: Die erste Antwort erklaert es ganz gut. Der Unterschied ist subtil und in der Alltagssprache sollte **ueber** meistens funktionieren. **Von** wird meistens im Zusammenhang mit einer Art Definition verwendet und oft in einer wenn - dann Konstruktion, z.B., "Wenn ich **von** Lebensfuehrungs-Krankheit spreche, dann meine ich ...", Fuer mich funktioniert **ueber** hier auch, aber zumindest in einem akademischen Kontext ist **von** wohl gebraeuchlicher. In einer Aussage wie "In der naechsten Vorlesung sprechen wir **ueber** Lebensfuehrungs-Krankheit." waere **von** falsch.

Comment: Okay, danke :-)

Comment: Willkommen bei German.SE. Bitte jegliche Klärung im Kommentar in die Antwort reineditieren.  Kommentare verschwinden manchmal ;-)

Comment: Das macht es klar. Danke vielmal.

Answer (score 0):

The former ("sprechen von") is defining the term "Lebensführungskrankenheiten" (albeit somewhat lamely). The latter ("sprechen über") describes the topic of conversation. In this context, that creates a non-sequitur: "Some diseases are caused by life style. Then we talk about life style diseases."

Comment: Welcome to German.SE. As far as I understand the question it is about the verb construction *sprechen von/über*  - not about a translation of the content of the sentence. Please reread the question and edit your answer so it does fit better. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Although there are subtle differences between "sprechen von" and "sprechen über", which are difficult to make out and which deserve a separate discussion, the use of "von" in the context you mention is a clear-cut one and does not properly refer to "speaking about something/someone", but to a term which is used to define something/someone. We can roughly translate it with "we label/name this...", as in: "wenn es um Leute geht, die stehlen, um überleben zu können, sprechen wir von "Armutskriminalität" (wenn it's about people who steal in order to survive, we label/name this "criminality out of poverty").